# Getting 'image.mapster is not a function' error when trying to use jQuery Mapster plugin

Tags: imagemapster

I'm trying to use the jQuery Mapster plugin to create an interactive image map on my HTML page. However, I'm encountering an error that says "'image.mapster is not a function'" in my browser's console. I've checked the script order, ensured jQuery is loaded, and followed the initialization steps provided in the documentation, but I'm still facing this issue.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"
></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script language="text/javascript" src="jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<img id="vegetables" src="test.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="312" name="carrots" title="312" href="" coords="830,841,924,780,992,921,910,962" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="305" name="asparagus" title="305" href="" coords="1570,686,1664,686,1660,838,1568,842" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="302" name="302" title="302" href="" coords="1855,684,1935,684,1937,838,1855,836" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="309" name="309" title="309" href="" coords="1156,699,1275,686,1281,840,1187,857" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="211" name="211" title="211" href="" coords="1031,996,1111,961,1144,1063,1074,1086" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="209" name="209" title="209" href="" coords="1201,936,1293,922,1291,1045,1221,1049" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="205" name="205" title="205" href="" coords="1570,1045,1664,1047,1664,920,1570,922" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="2" name="2" title="2" href="" coords="1773,1262,1916,1260,1914,1070,1773,1072" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="6" name="6" title="6" href="" coords="1379,1223,1472,1223,1472,1072,1379,1070" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="10" name="10" title="10" href="" coords="1160,1285,1084,1117,998,1162,1107,1303" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="12" name="12" title="12" href="" coords="912,1318,963,1252,926,1219,869,1289" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="14" name="14" title="14" href="" coords="799,1473,824,1387,1004,1443,988,1500" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="16" name="16" title="16" href="" coords="797,1586,984,1563,998,1621,818,1684" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="18" name="18" title="18" href="" coords="859,1779,1023,1680,1062,1727,916,1852" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="20" name="20" title="20" href="" coords="994,1924,1107,1764,1154,1791,1076,1971" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="23" name="23" title="23" href="" coords="1275,2016,1377,2018,1373,1852,1279,1850" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="28" name="28" title="28" href="" coords="1769,1854,1914,1852,1918,2018,1771,2016" shape="poly">
</map>
<div style="clear: both; width: 500px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black;" id="selections"></div>
<script>

   // a cross reference of area names to text to be shown for each area
   var xref = {
        carrots: "<b>Carrots</b> are delicious and may turn your skin orange!",
        asparagus: "<b>Asparagus</b> is one of the first vegetables of the spring. " 
            +"Being a dark green, it's great for you, and has interesting side effects.",
        squash: "<b>Squash</b> is a winter vegetable, and not eaten raw too much. Is that really squash?",
        redpepper: "<b>Red peppers</b> are actually the same as green peppers, they've just been left on "
            +"the vine longer. Delicious when fire-roasted.",
        yellowpepper: "Similar to red peppers, <b>yellow peppers</b> are sometimes sweeter.",
        celery: "<b>Celery</b> is a fascinating vegetable. Being mostly water, it actually takes your body "
            +"more calories to process it than it provides.",
        cucumbers: "<b>Cucumbers</b> are cool.",
        broccoli: "<b>Broccoli</b> is like a forest of goodness in your mouth. And very good for you. "
            +"Eat lots of broccoli!",
        dip: "Everything here is good for you but this one. <b>Don't be a dip!</b>"
    };
    
    var defaultDipTooltip = 'I know you want the dip. But it\'s loaded with saturated fat, just skip it '
        +'and enjoy as many delicious, crisp vegetables as you can eat.';
    
    

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var image = $('#vegetables');    
    image.mapster(
    {
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        fillColor: "d42e16",
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: "3320FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        singleSelect: true,
        mapKey: 'name',
        listKey: 'name',
        onClick: function (e) {
            var newToolTip = defaultDipTooltip;
            
            // update text depending on area selected
            $('#selections').html(xref[e.key]);
            
            // if Asparagus selected, change the tooltip
            if (e.key === 'asparagus') {
                newToolTip = "OK. I know I have come down on the dip before, but let's be real. "
                    +"Raw asparagus without any of that delicious ranch and onion dressing "
                    +"slathered all over it is not so good.";
            }
            image.mapster('set_options', { 
                areas: [{
                    key: "dip",
                    toolTip: newToolTip
                    }]
                });
        },
        showToolTip: true,
        toolTipClose: ["tooltip-click", "area-click"],
        areas: [
            {
                key: "redpepper",
                fillColor: "ffffff"
            },
            {
                key: "yellowpepper",
                fillColor: "000000"
            },
            {
                key: "carrots",
                fillColor: "000000"
            },
            {
                key: "dip",
                toolTip: defaultDipTooltip
            },
            {
                key: "asparagus",
                strokeColor: "FFFFFF"
            }
            ]
    });
})

    </script>
```

I've ensured that jQuery is loaded before the Mapster script, and I've followed the proper initialization steps. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

I'm trying to use the jQuery Mapster plugin to create an interactive image map on my HTML page. However, I'm encountering an error that says "'image.mapster is not a function'" in my browser's console. I've checked the script order, ensured jQuery is loaded, and followed the initialization steps provided in the documentation, but I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: You seem to be loading jQuery twice, first the 3.6.0 version and two lines later the 1.7.1 version, is that intended?

Comment: I saw that after posting it here. I have removed the second line. But mapster is still not loading for me

Comment: Please also edit the code in your question to remove the line there as well. Furthermore it would help if you can make the image available, that would make it easier to reproduce the problem.